# Show all the fields from JOIN table in the UNION?

Tags: mysql, database

How to show some fields from `tariff_data` table that is already include in the UNION with JOIN?

For example:

```
SELECT  X.* FROM
    (
         SELECT phone_id, tariff_id, active  FROM table1 WHERE id = 5
      UNION
          SELECT dgt.phone_id, tns.tariff_id, dgt.active  FROM  table2 AS dgt 
                JOIN tariff_data AS tns ON tns.something = dgt.something
          WHERE id = 5
    ) as X
```

Comment: Isn't tariff_id a field from tariff_data? Do you wish to include a field that is not in table1?

Comment: Yes it can include all the fields even not in `table1`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  X.* FROM
(
    SELECT phone_id, tariff_id, active, null as "somefield"  FROM table1 WHERE id = 5
      UNION
    SELECT dgt.phone_id, tns.tariff_id, dgt.active, tns.somefield FROM  table2 AS dgt 
            JOIN tariff_data AS tns ON tns.something = dgt.something
    WHERE id = 5
) as X
```

Comment: Ahh I see and it is a bit ugly though.

Comment: Yeah - I modified the answer - you can set the non-existent field to anything if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to include the field from tariff_data in both Select statements, setting the first to null or whatever you like:

```
SELECT  X.* FROM
(
    SELECT phone_id, tariff_id, active, null as "somefield"  FROM table1 WHERE id = 5
      UNION
    SELECT dgt.phone_id, tns.tariff_id, dgt.active, tns.somefield FROM  table2 AS dgt 
            JOIN tariff_data AS tns ON tns.something = dgt.something
    WHERE id = 5
) as X
```